# How to solve Msg 4104 for SQL Server in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am modifying a stored procedure which is joining some tables and returning the output. I want to include a new table that will perform a join operation and with those existing table. And while doing that I am getting an "Msg 4104" while including that condition. I saw that it is for an alias problem which is in the select statement, but I am new to stored procedure and can not figure out how it is occurring. I am posting my code please someone help. This is portion of the code which I am developing

```
CREATE TABLE #es_ediconsolidate 
( 
   [txtype]          [CHAR](2) NULL, 
   [txdesc]          [VARCHAR](40) NULL, 
   [txrefno]         [CHAR](25) NULL, 
   [clntcode]        [CHAR](5) NULL, 
   [polno]           [CHAR](10) NULL, 
   [certno]          [CHAR](10) NULL, 
   [depcode]         [DECIMAL](5, 0) NULL, 
   [deptype]         [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [namefirst]       [CHAR](50) NULL, 
   [namelast]        [CHAR](50) NULL, 
   [namemid]         [CHAR](2) NULL, 
   [inieffdt]        [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [status]          [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [chgeffdt]        [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [suboffcode]      [CHAR](3) NULL, 
   [departcd]        [CHAR](6) NULL, 
   [memidno]         [CHAR](12) NULL, 
   [dob]             [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [sex]             [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [marital]         [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [occupation]      [CHAR](20) NULL, 
   [empno]           [CHAR](10) NULL, 
   [empdt]           [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [salary]          [DECIMAL](13, 2) NULL, 
   [bankac]          [CHAR](40) NULL, 
   [memnation]       [CHAR](3) NULL, 
   [effdate]         [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [bankcode]        [CHAR](4) NULL, 
   [salarymode]      [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [bankactype]      [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [bankaceffdate]   [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [bankacstatus]    [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [firstcovdt]      [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [maxageexemptind] [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [vipstatus]       [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [sponsoridno]     [VARCHAR](20) NULL, 
   [passportno]      [CHAR](15) NULL, 
   [nationalidno]    [CHAR](30) NULL, 
   [bankname]        [CHAR](40) NULL, 
   [branchname]      [CHAR](40) NULL, 
   [branchaddress]   [CHAR](40) NULL, 
   [bankcurrency]    [CHAR](3) NULL, 
   [swiftcode]       [CHAR](15) NULL, 
   [servicedeskid]   [CHAR](10) NULL, 
   [servicedeskdate] [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [dmpindicator]    [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [salarychgeffdt]  [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [studentind]      [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [outcntyind]      [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [prodcode]        [CHAR](5) NULL, 
   [benplncd]        [CHAR](3) NULL, 
   [covgcode]        [CHAR](5) NULL, 
   [proposedsa]      [DECIMAL](11, 0) NULL, 
   [prdstatus]       [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [benid]           [CHAR](20) NULL, 
   [benname]         [CHAR](40) NULL, 
   [benrelat]        [CHAR](15) NULL, 
   [beneffdt]        [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [benshare]        [DECIMAL](5, 4) NULL, 
   [remark]          [CHAR](16) NULL, 
   [rcdsts]          [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [rcdusrid]        [CHAR](20) NULL, 
   [rcddtstmp]       [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [txstatus]        [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [uploadusrid]     [VARCHAR](20) NULL, 
   [uploadtime]      [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [errorcode]       [CHAR](6) NULL, 
   [errormsg]        [VARCHAR](100) NULL, 
   [isprocessing]    [CHAR](1) NULL, 
   [parentclient]    [VARCHAR](40) NULL, 
   [agentname]       [VARCHAR](101) NULL, 
   [packagecode]     [CHAR](35) NULL, 
   [province]        [CHAR](20) NULL, 
   [cardprinteddate] [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [processedtime]   [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [adminuserid]     [VARCHAR](20) NULL, 
   [email]           [VARCHAR](60) NULL, 
   [mobileno]        [VARCHAR](20) NULL,       
   [city]           [VARCHAR] (28),
   [iqamaExpDate]    [DATETIME] NULL,
   [terminationReason] [VARCHAR] (1),
   [LifeVestInd] [CHAR](1),
   [LSBIndicator] [CHAR](1),
   [UIDnumber] [VARCHAR] (20),
   [VisaPlaceOfIssue] [VARCHAR] (50),
   [eligdays]        [DECIMAL](3, 0) NULL, 
   [certtype]        [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
   [BENIDTYPE]      [VARCHAR](30) NULL, 
   [BENADDR1]       [VARCHAR](30) NULL, 
   [BENADDR2]       [VARCHAR](30) NULL, 
   [BENADDR3]       [VARCHAR](30) NULL, 
   [BENADDR4]       [VARCHAR](30) NULL, 
   [BENNATIONALITY] [CHAR](3) NULL, 
   [BENDOB]         [DATETIME] NULL, 
   [BENFILE]        [CHAR](1) NULL,  
   [FILETYPE]       [CHAR](5) NULL,  
   [FILETYPEDESC]   [VARCHAR](255) NULL,  
   [FILEFORMAT]     [VARCHAR](255) NULL,  
   [FILESIZE]       [INT] NULL,  
   [FILEPATH]       [CHAR](1) NULL,
   [FILETYPEFLAG]   [CHAR](2) NULL,
   [oldPolicyNo]    [CHAR](10) NULL,
   [oldSubOffCode]  [CHAR](3) NULL,
   [roleid]         [CHAR](20) NULL, 
   [submitted by]    [char] (200) NULL,
   [oldbenplncd]    [char] (3) NULL,
   [SPONSORTYPE]    [INT] NULL  ,
   [GROSSSALARYRANGE][CHAR](1) NULL,
   [SALARYBASEDONCOMMISSION][CHAR](3) NULL,
   [RESIDINGEMIRATE][CHAR](20) NULL,
   [RESIDINGLOCATION][CHAR](20) NULL,
   [WORKLOCATIONEMIRATE][CHAR](20) NULL,
   [WORKLOCATION][CHAR](20) NULL,
   [MEMBERINSURANCEINSIXMONTH][CHAR](50) NULL,
   [VISASPONSORID][CHAR](20) NULL,
   [SPONSORCONTACTNUMBER][CHAR](50) NULL,
   [SPONSOREMAILID][CHAR](50) NULL,

) 
  /* End Temp table for Distributed out put*/

  INSERT INTO  #es_ediconsolidate 
    SELECT DISTINCT A.txtype,X.txdesc,txrefno,A.clntcode,A.polno,A.certno,A.depcode,deptype,namefirst,namelast,
            namemid,A.inieffdt,A.status,A.chgeffdt,suboffcode,departcd,memidno,dob,sex,marital,occupation,empno, 
            empdt,salary,A.bankac,memnation,A.effdate,A.bankcode,A.salarymode,bankactype,bankaceffdate,bankacstatus, 
            firstcovdt,maxageexemptind,vipstatus,sponsoridno,passportno,nationalidno,bankname,branchname,branchaddress, 
            bankcurrency,swiftcode,servicedeskid,servicedeskdate,dmpindicator,salarychgeffdt,studentind, outcntyind,
            PRODCODE =NULL,BENPLNCD =NULL,COVGCODE =NULL,PROPOSEDSA =NULL,PRDSTATUS =NULL,BENID = NULL,BENNAME =NULL, 
            BENRELAT =NULL,BENEFFDT =NULL,BENSHARE = NULL,REMARK =NULL,A.rcdsts,A.rcdusrid,A.rcddtstmp,txstatus,uploadusrid, 
            uploadtime,errorcode,errormsg, isprocessing,TR.SPONSORTYPE,TR.GROSSSALARYRANGE,TR.SALARYBASEDONCOMMISSION,
            TR.RESIDINGEMIRATE,TR.RESIDINGLOCATION,TR.WORKLOCATIONEMIRATE,TR.WORKLOCATION,TR.MEMBERINSURANCEINSIXMONTH,
            TR.VISASPONSORID,TR.SPONSORCONTACTNUMBER,TR.SPONSOREMAILID,

FROM   tmemtrans A  (NOLOCK)
                   INNER JOIN es_txtypes X  (NOLOCK)
                           ON A.txtype = X.txtype 
                   INNER JOIN tpolicy P  (NOLOCK)
                           ON A.polno = P.polno 
                   INNER JOIN tpolpdt TP (nolock) 
                           ON A.polno = tp.polno 

                   --INNER JOIN tpolpdtcom tcom (nolock)
                   --        ON tp.polno = tcom.polno and tp.prodcode = tcom.prodcode and tp.effdate = tcom.effdate and tcom.prducode in (select es_usercode.code from es_usercode where es_usercode.userid= a.UPLOADUSRID union select es_usercode.code from es_usercode, es_userrole where es_usercode.userid=es_userrole.supervisorid and es_userrole.userid=a.UPLOADUSRID) 
                   left JOIN tclient C (nolock) 
                           ON --A.profilecode = c.clntcode 
                           --AND
                            P.clntcode = c.clntcode 
                    --Here i am including the join ----

                          JOIN TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO TR (nolock)
                          ON TR.CLNTCODE = A.CLNTCODE
                          AND TR.CERTNO = A.CERTNO
                          AND TR.DEPCODE = A.DEPCODE
                   INNER JOIN @PolNosCanAccess polnos  on polnos.polno= A.polno
```

Added my full select statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.txtype,X.txdesc, txrefno, A.clntcode,A.polno,certno,DEPCODE=NULL,DEPTYPE=NULL, 
        NAMEFIRST=NULL,NAMELAST=NULL,NAMEMID=NULL,INIEFFDT=NULL,STATUS=NULL,CHGEFFDT=NULL,SUBOFFCODE=NULL, 
        DEPARTCD=NULL,MEMIDNO=NULL,DOB=NULL,SEX=NULL,MARITAL=NULL,OCCUPATION=NULL,EMPNO=NULL,EMPDT=NULL, 
        SALARY=NULL,BANKAC=NULL,MEMNATION=NULL,EFFDATE=NULL,BANKCODE=NULL,SALARYMODE=NULL,BANKACTYPE=NULL, 
        BANKACEFFDATE=NULL,BANKACSTATUS=NULL,FIRSTCOVDT=NULL,MAXAGEEXEMPTIND=NULL,VIPSTATUS=NULL, 
        SPONSORIDNO=NULL,PASSPORTNO=NULL,NATIONALIDNO=NULL,BANKNAME=NULL,BRANCHNAME=NULL,BRANCHADDRESS=NULL, 
        BANKCURRENCY=NULL,SWIFTCODE=NULL,SERVICEDESKID=NULL,SERVICEDESKDATE=NULL,DMPINDICATOR=NULL, 
        SALARYCHGEFFDT=NULL,STUDENTIND=NULL,OUTCNTYIND=NULL,PRODCODE =NULL,BENPLNCD =NULL,COVGCODE =NULL, 
        PROPOSEDSA =NULL,PRDSTATUS =NULL,benid,benname,benrelat,beneffdt,benshare,remark,A.rcdsts, 
        A.rcdusrid,A.rcddtstmp,txstatus,uploadusrid,uploadtime,errorcode,errormsg,isprocessing,TR.SPONSORTYPE,TR.GROSSSALARYRANGE,TR.SALARYBASEDONCOMMISSION,
            TR.RESIDINGEMIRATE,TR.RESIDINGLOCATION,TR.WORKLOCATIONEMIRATE,TR.WORKLOCATION,TR.MEMBERINSURANCEINSIXMONTH,
            TR.VISASPONSORID,TR.SPONSORCONTACTNUMBER,TR.SPONSOREMAILID,
        case when A.roleid = 'agent' or A.roleid = 'broker' or A.roleid = 'brokeradmin' or A.roleid = 'admin' then null else  
                case when A.roleid= 'policyholder'  
                    then P.poldesc  
                    else c.clntname
                end 
            end  as 'PARENTCLIENT',
            ''  as  'AGENTNAME',
        'packagecode' = (select PackageDesc from dbo.TPackageType (NOLOCK) where packagecode = P.packagecode),P.province,'' as 'CARDPRINTEDDATE',processedtime, 
        adminuserid,EMAIL=NULL,MOBILENO=NULL,city=NULL,iqamaExpDate=NULL,terminationReason=NULL,LifeVestInd=NULL,LSBIndicator=NULL,UIDnumber=NULL,VisaPlaceOfIssue=NULL,ELIGDAYS=NULL,CERTTYPE=NULL,BENIDTYPE,BENADDR1,BENADDR2,BENADDR3,BENADDR4,BENNATIONALITY,BENDOB,CASE WHEN BENFILE IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS 'BENFILE',FILETYPE=NULL,FILETYPEDESC=NULL,FILEFORMAT=NULL,FILESIZE=NULL,FILEPATH=NULL,FILETYPEFLAG=NULL,oldPolicyNo=NULL,oldSubOffCode=NULL,A.roleid ,
        case a.roleid when 'brokeradmin' then  (select top 1 tproducer.prduname from tproducer (NOLOCK), es_usercode (NOLOCK) where es_usercode.userid= a.UPLOADUSRID and es_usercode.code=tproducer.prducode )  
                              when 'agencymanager' then (select tagency.agyname from tagency (NOLOCK), es_usercode (NOLOCK) where es_usercode.userid=a.UPLOADUSRID and substring(es_usercode.code, 1, 3) = tagency.agycode ) 
                              when 'unitmanager' then ( select top 1 tproducer.prduname from tproducer (NOLOCK), es_usercode (NOLOCK) where es_usercode.userid=a.UPLOADUSRID and es_usercode.code=tproducer.prducode)
                              when 'policyholderadmin' then (select top 1 tclient.clntname from tclient (NOLOCK), es_usercode (NOLOCK) where es_usercode.userid=a.UPLOADUSRID and es_usercode.code=tclient.clntcode) 
                              when 'broker' then (select top 1 tproducer.prduname from tproducer (NOLOCK), es_usercode (NOLOCK), es_userrole (NOLOCK) where es_usercode.userid=es_userrole.supervisorid and es_userrole.userid=a.UPLOADUSRID and es_usercode.code=tproducer.prducode)  
                              when 'agent' then (select top 1 tproducer.prduname from tproducer (NOLOCK), es_usercode where es_usercode.userid=a.UPLOADUSRID and es_usercode.code=tproducer.prducode) 
                              when 'policyholder' then( select tpolicy.poldesc from tpolicy (NOLOCK) where tpolicy.polno =a.polno)
                              when 'member' then (select im.namefirst + ' ' + im.namelast from tmember im (NOLOCK) where im.certno=a.certno and im.clntcode=a.clntcode)
                end     'submitted by',oldbenplncd=NULL
        FROM   tbenftrans A (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN es_txtypes X (NOLOCK)
        ON A.txtype = X.txtype 
        INNER JOIN tpolicy P (NOLOCK)
        ON A.polno = P.polno 
        INNER JOIN tpolpdt TP(nolock)
        ON A.polno = TP.polno 
        --INNER JOIN tpolpdtcom tcom (nolock)
        --ON tp.polno = tcom.polno and tp.prodcode = tcom.prodcode and tp.effdate = tcom.effdate and tcom.prducode in (select es_usercode.code from es_usercode where es_usercode.userid= a.UPLOADUSRID union select es_usercode.code from es_usercode, es_userrole where es_usercode.userid=es_userrole.supervisorid and es_userrole.userid=a.UPLOADUSRID) 
        left JOIN tclient C (nolock) 
        ON  P.clntcode = c.clntcode
```

But I am getting the error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ES_CONSOLIDATELIST_ADMIN_MEMBER, Line 360
>   The multi-part identifier "TR.SPONSORTYPE" could not be bound.

This is my `TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO` table schema

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    [CLNTCODE]
  ,[CERTNO]
  ,[DEPCODE]
  ,[SPONSORTYPE]
  ,[GROSSSALARYRANGE]
  ,[SALARYBASEDONCOMMISSION]
  ,[RESIDINGEMIRATE]
  ,[RESIDINGLOCATION]
  ,[WORKLOCATIONEMIRATE]
  ,[WORKLOCATION]
  ,[MEMBERINSURANCEINSIXMONTH]
  ,[VISASPONSORID]
  ,[SPONSORCONTACTNUMBER]
  ,[SPONSOREMAILID]
FROM 
    [eService_EP].[dbo].[TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO]
```

Somebody please help

Comment: The message is very clear, there is no `SPONSORTYPE`column in `TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO`  table

Comment: @CiucaS but the coloumn is there in the table

Comment: add sp_help 'TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO ' to answer

Comment: Post the table definitions also there is comma `TR.SPONSOREMAILID,` at the end of the `select` statement, before `from` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @CiucaS  there is a case statement after the SPONSOREMAILID thats why putted the comma.

Comment: @JeetChatterjee then add the full select statement. Is your procedure database the same as the table database?

Comment: @CiucaS added the full select statement

Comment: Is your procedure in eService_EP database?

Comment: Try to add `[eService_EP].[dbo].[TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO]` instead of [TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO ] in the join statement.

Comment: getting this error  Msg 117, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ES_CONSOLIDATELIST_ADMIN_MEMBER, Line 408
The object name 'eService_EP.dbo.eService_EP.dbo.TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 3.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ES_CONSOLIDATELIST_ADMIN_MEMBER, Line 415
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You've added `eService_EP.dbo.` two times

Comment: Removed that again the same error as previous

Comment: @CiucaS please help can not figure it out

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
The multi-part identifier "TR.SPONSORTYPE" could not be bound.
```

This error is the way SQL shows you that he does not now what you mean by `TR.SPONSORTYPE` ( he can't find the table and column). This could be due to some factors most likely there is a type but it also could be the databases. If the query below doesn't work it means you haven't provided with enought information so we can give you a solution.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.txtype, 
                X.txdesc, 
                txrefno, 
                A.clntcode, 
                A.polno, 
                certno, 
                DEPCODE=NULL, 
                DEPTYPE=NULL, 
                NAMEFIRST=NULL, 
                NAMELAST=NULL, 
                NAMEMID=NULL, 
                INIEFFDT=NULL, 
                STATUS=NULL, 
                CHGEFFDT=NULL, 
                SUBOFFCODE=NULL, 
                DEPARTCD=NULL, 
                MEMIDNO=NULL, 
                DOB=NULL, 
                SEX=NULL, 
                MARITAL=NULL, 
                OCCUPATION=NULL, 
                EMPNO=NULL, 
                EMPDT=NULL, 
                SALARY=NULL, 
                BANKAC=NULL, 
                MEMNATION=NULL, 
                EFFDATE=NULL, 
                BANKCODE=NULL, 
                SALARYMODE=NULL, 
                BANKACTYPE=NULL, 
                BANKACEFFDATE=NULL, 
                BANKACSTATUS=NULL, 
                FIRSTCOVDT=NULL, 
                MAXAGEEXEMPTIND=NULL, 
                VIPSTATUS=NULL, 
                SPONSORIDNO=NULL, 
                PASSPORTNO=NULL, 
                NATIONALIDNO=NULL, 
                BANKNAME=NULL, 
                BRANCHNAME=NULL, 
                BRANCHADDRESS=NULL, 
                BANKCURRENCY=NULL, 
                SWIFTCODE=NULL, 
                SERVICEDESKID=NULL, 
                SERVICEDESKDATE=NULL, 
                DMPINDICATOR=NULL, 
                SALARYCHGEFFDT=NULL, 
                STUDENTIND=NULL, 
                OUTCNTYIND=NULL, 
                PRODCODE =NULL, 
                BENPLNCD =NULL, 
                COVGCODE =NULL, 
                PROPOSEDSA =NULL, 
                PRDSTATUS =NULL, 
                benid, 
                benname, 
                benrelat, 
                beneffdt, 
                benshare, 
                remark, 
                A.rcdsts, 
                A.rcdusrid, 
                A.rcddtstmp, 
                txstatus, 
                uploadusrid, 
                uploadtime, 
                errorcode, 
                errormsg, 
                isprocessing, 
                tr.sponsortype, 
                tr.grosssalaryrange, 
                tr.salarybasedoncommission, 
                tr.residingemirate, 
                tr.residinglocation, 
                tr.worklocationemirate, 
                tr.worklocation, 
                tr.memberinsuranceinsixmonth, 
                tr.visasponsorid, 
                tr.sponsorcontactnumber, 
                tr.sponsoremailid, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN A.roleid = 'agent' 
                        OR A.roleid = 'broker' 
                        OR A.roleid = 'brokeradmin' 
                        OR A.roleid = 'admin' THEN NULL 
                  ELSE 
                    CASE 
                      WHEN A.roleid = 'policyholder' THEN P.poldesc 
                      ELSE c.clntname 
                    END 
                END AS 'PARENTCLIENT', 
                ''  AS 'AGENTNAME', 
                'packagecode' = (SELECT packagedesc 
                                 FROM   dbo.tpackagetype (nolock) 
                                 WHERE  packagecode = P.packagecode), 
                P.province, 
                ''  AS 'CARDPRINTEDDATE', 
                processedtime, 
                adminuserid, 
                EMAIL=NULL, 
                MOBILENO=NULL, 
                city=NULL, 
                iqamaExpDate=NULL, 
                terminationReason=NULL, 
                LifeVestInd=NULL, 
                LSBIndicator=NULL, 
                UIDnumber=NULL, 
                VisaPlaceOfIssue=NULL, 
                ELIGDAYS=NULL, 
                CERTTYPE=NULL, 
                benidtype, 
                benaddr1, 
                benaddr2, 
                benaddr3, 
                benaddr4, 
                bennationality, 
                bendob, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN benfile IS NULL THEN 'N' 
                  ELSE 'Y' 
                END AS 'BENFILE', 
                FILETYPE=NULL, 
                FILETYPEDESC=NULL, 
                FILEFORMAT=NULL, 
                FILESIZE=NULL, 
                FILEPATH=NULL, 
                FILETYPEFLAG=NULL, 
                oldPolicyNo=NULL, 
                oldSubOffCode=NULL, 
                A.roleid, 
                CASE a.roleid 
                  WHEN 'brokeradmin' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 tproducer.prduname 
                                           FROM   tproducer (nolock), 
                                                  es_usercode (nolock) 
                                           WHERE 
                  es_usercode.userid = a.uploadusrid 
                  AND es_usercode.code = tproducer.prducode) 
                  WHEN 'agencymanager' THEN (SELECT tagency.agyname 
                                             FROM   tagency (nolock), 
                                                    es_usercode (nolock) 
                                             WHERE 
                  es_usercode.userid = a.uploadusrid 
                  AND Substring(es_usercode.code, 1, 3) = 
                      tagency.agycode) 
                  WHEN 'unitmanager' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 tproducer.prduname 
                                           FROM   tproducer (nolock), 
                                                  es_usercode (nolock) 
                                           WHERE 
                  es_usercode.userid = a.uploadusrid 
                  AND es_usercode.code = tproducer.prducode) 
                  WHEN 'policyholderadmin' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 tclient.clntname 
                                                 FROM   tclient (nolock), 
                                                        es_usercode (nolock) 
                                                 WHERE 
                  es_usercode.userid = a.uploadusrid 
                  AND es_usercode.code = tclient.clntcode) 
                  WHEN 'broker' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 tproducer.prduname 
                                      FROM   tproducer (nolock), 
                                             es_usercode (nolock), 
                                             es_userrole (nolock) 
                                      WHERE  es_usercode.userid = 
                                             es_userrole.supervisorid 
                                             AND 
                                     es_userrole.userid = a.uploadusrid 
                                             AND es_usercode.code = 
                                                 tproducer.prducode) 
                  WHEN 'agent' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 tproducer.prduname 
                                     FROM   tproducer (nolock), 
                                            es_usercode 
                                     WHERE  es_usercode.userid = a.uploadusrid 
                                            AND es_usercode.code = 
                                                tproducer.prducode) 
                  WHEN 'policyholder' THEN(SELECT tpolicy.poldesc 
                                           FROM   tpolicy (nolock) 
                                           WHERE  tpolicy.polno = a.polno) 
                  WHEN 'member' THEN (SELECT im.namefirst + ' ' + im.namelast 
                                      FROM   tmember im (nolock) 
                                      WHERE  im.certno = a.certno 
                                             AND im.clntcode = a.clntcode) 
                END 'submitted by', 
                oldbenplncd=NULL 
FROM   tbenftrans A (nolock) 
       INNER JOIN es_txtypes X (nolock) ON A.txtype = X.txtype 
       INNER JOIN tpolicy P (nolock) ON A.polno = P.polno 
       INNER JOIN tpolpdt TP(nolock) ON A.polno = TP.polno       
       LEFT JOIN tclient C (nolock) ON P.clntcode = c.clntcode  
       JOIN eService_EP.dbo.TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO TR (nolock) ON TR.CLNTCODE = A.CLNTCODE
                 AND TR.CERTNO = A.CERTNO
                 AND TR.DEPCODE = A.DEPCODE
       INNER JOIN @PolNosCanAccess polnos  on polnos.polno= A.polno
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but can you tell where you have changed my query ?i can not find the position please

Comment: I changed the JOIN with the `TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO ` table. Use this select for the insert statement.

Comment: thanks but where is the change in the join ?i can not see

Comment: It is same as before

Comment: i can not see the difference in the join condition.Please help

Comment: it has the database reference `  JOIN eService_EP.dbo.TMEMBERREGULATORYINFO TR`. Run the select, see if it works. If it doesn't come back with the error.